# I am calling a concurrent ajax call, each ajax call in other's post back function.

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

these ajax calls are searching the data from DB one by one.(synchronously) and the search results are loaded on popup page. 
what i want is when i close these popup page by cross button i want to stop the ajax calls and return to my website continuing other functions.

right now i am facing the problem is like when i close the popup while the request execution my application gets hanged.

please find the attached code below:

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
                    if(srchTxt != '' && srchTxt != undefined){
                       $('#frmHomeSearch').find('input[name=me]').val('');
                       $('#frmHomeSearch').find('input[name=to]').val('PGLOADPARTYSRCHRESULTS');
                       $('#frmHomeSearch').find('input[name=srchTxt]').val(srchTxt);
                       $('#frmHomeSearch').find('input[name=isCustSrch]').val(isCustSrch);
                       $('#frmHomeSearch').find('input[name=isSysUsrSrch]').val(isSysUsrSrch);

                           provajax.submitAndLoad('#partySrchRes','#container','#frmHomeSearch', function(){
                                 setTimeout(function(){
                                       $('#frmHomeSearch').find('input[name=to]').val('PGCODEFORASSET');
                                       provajax.submitAndLoad('#assetSrchRes','#container','#frmHomeSearch', function(){
                                                setTimeout(function(){
                                                       $('#frmHomeSearch').find('input[name=to]').val('PGCODECREDITSRCHRESULTS');
                                                       provajax.submitAndLoad('#requestSrchRes','#container','#frmHomeSearch', function(){
                                                               setTimeout(function(){            $('#frmHomeSearch').find('input[name=to]').val('PGCODECREDITLINESRCHRESULTS');
                                                                provajax.submitAndLoad('#transSrchRes','#container','#frmHomeSearch');
                                                               }, 1500);

                                                       });
                                                   }, 1500);
                                            });
                                   }, 1500);

                           });
                       }
                   }
```

and i am closing the popup through the following code:

```
<a id="cancel_icon" class="cancel_icon" onclick="close(); " href="#.">
```

Comment: what does your `close()` function do?

Comment: @NikhilPatil it closes the the popup which load the search result brought by above ajax calls.

Comment: Do you want to stop AJAX calls from the moment you close the popup on ward? Of course if you re-open the popup that loop restarts I guess.

Comment: @MarcoCI yes i want to stop the execution of ajax calls from the moment i close the popup

Comment: Please help somebody..